# What causes the anomaly of the first row of my grid compiled of hexagons, or how to delete it?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Update: It seemed to be a glitch. I set my modulo to -2 like alambre recommended and it worked. Then I set it back to 2 and it didn't change at all (setting to -2 the first time did change it)

I have made it so that every second row moves a little to the left using mainly modulo, floor, and index input, however the first row moves right for some reason.

Images of moving driven by the divide node:
[image]
[image]

[image]

I have no idea what is causing it and I seem to have done everything like the tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EboNtLKn_m8&list=PLVm7O9OzjT6EIDtFGC67QxGsHkz3_RbIw&index=13)

What is causing and how to solve it?

Full node build (not adding the two modulos together doesn't change anything):
[image]

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UYtOGPmLYwZFxC9uTrXXwC4zdCdxIFbj/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: the "best" thing you can do is follow the tutorial again - step by step - exactly how Erindale did it. His tutorials work (i watched many of his too). But if you want us to repair/help you, pls provide blend file so we don't have to rebuild it. Thanks.

Comment: just had a quick look if you change the modulo 2 to modulo -2 in the grid section it works I think... didn't check the tutorial to compare where's the problem

Comment: weird glitch :p